# Guessing game in java using math.random

Tags: java

Hi I'm trying to use Math.random to generate a random number between 0 and 100, then ask a user to enter a number between 0 and 100, or -1 to quit. If the number is out of bounds (and not -1), ask the user to enter a new number. If the user doesn't guess the number correctly, tell the user if the random number is higher or lower than the guessed number. Let the user make guesses until they enter the correct number or they enter -1. If they guess the correct number, tell the user how many tries it took and start the game again. It will Continue to play until the user quits.

I'm stuck on how to only get the user to enter 0-100 and on how to exit the loop by entering -1

This is what I have so far, any help would be appreciated !

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionOne
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
   int guess;

   System.out.println("Guess a number between 0-100");


   while(guess != a){
   guess = keyboard.nextInt();
   if (guess > a)
   {  
     System.out.println("The number is lower!");

   }
   else if (guess < a) 
   {
    System.out.println("higher!");

   }
   else 
   {
     System.out.println("Congratulations.You guessed the number with" + count + "tries!");
   }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem yet?

Comment: To summarize, your question is: `"Here are some requirements, here's some unexplained code, and nowhere will I post a specific answerable question"` -- Come on now, please improve this question. At least explain what your code does, what it doesn't do, where you're stuck, what you don't understand. Don't ask a lazy question please but rather put some effort into it.

Comment: There's a chance this person is totally new to coding - they probably need a bit of hand-holding. I know a lot of people will be kids with programming tasks, but we can still show that we're a community of people who are willing to help by suggesting improvements without totally giving them the answers.

Comment: @aho: no one can criticize ignorance, heck, we're all born ignorant, but we can criticize lazy questions, one where the poster puts absolutely no effort into the asking, and when first posted, that's what he did. It has improved some, and I will give him credit for that.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but we've all been lazy. Based on this person's s/o counters, they may not be too familiar with the preferred practices in s/o. (I know my counters are low too, but i've been much more of a taker than a giver in s/o, and am trying to restore the balance now that i'm taking a break from work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, your call to keyboard.nextInt() (and its corresponding println of "Guess a number between 0-100") should be within your while loop.

Then you should consider changing your while loop to

```
while (true) {
    // read input from user
    if (guess < value) { // tell user their guess is too low
    } else if (guess > value) { // tell user their guess is too high
    } else { // tell user congrats, and call break to exit the while loop }
    }
}
```

Once you get that right, you can work on the nice-to-haves, like checking numbers guessed are within bounds, keeping track of how many guesses they've done, etc

Comment: how do I  loop this continuously until the user enters -1?

Comment: There are a couple of ways. You should play around with the code until it makes sense. Don't be shy to use System.out.println() to tell you what's going on. I'm sure you can do this

Comment: I now have this code but can't loop it continuously http://pastebin.com/sa7dw6ra :( That's my last and only problem

Comment: alright, good stuff! So if you want to repeat the game over and over, can you think of a control structure which allows you to repeat things until some condition is true? (hint: you've already used one in this code)

Comment: should i use a while loop then put everything inside it??

Comment: maybe - but you should definitely try and see what (if anything) breaks! And then you should try to fix it. And when you do, you should crack open the bubbly

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm not sure what my condition will be if i use the while loop (i'm sorry for asking too much questions, i'm just a beginner in java)

Comment: No problem. Use 2 while loops. The outermost one will be while (true) { // initialise a game (i.e. get the computer to choose a random number, set counter to 0, etc), and then read a value from the keyboard; then you'll have another while loop within (which would basically be the one presented in this response - make the first if ( ) check for -1 and take the action you want, and keep the rest of the if ( ) tests in place. Try that.

Comment: update: http://pastebin.com/tXUV8g4c tried it but the program stops after asking the user for the second time. Is it wrong?

Comment: You need to re-read (very carefully) what I said in my last comment

Comment: okay now i have this code and it loops continuously now http://pastebin.com/eSRjEEd7 but when i entered the correct number it just basically asks for that number again.

Comment: That's definitely a step in the wrong direction. Your previous attempt was better. Please try to work through a flow diagram if the visualisation helps - and then code it up from there; I get the impression you're typing up code without fully understanding the problem and without working out the logic that will drive this code. Good luck

Comment: got it now! appreciate your patience! :)